# $p \geq$ 7 show $\Big( \frac{n}{p} \Big)=\Big( \frac{n+1}{p} \Big) =1$ for atleast one n in the set $\{ 1,2,\ldots,,9 \}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

Suppose that p is prime $\geq$ 7.Show that $\Big( \frac{n}{p} 
\Big)=\Big( \frac{n+1}{p} \Big) =1$ for atleast one n in the set $\{ 1,2,3,\ldots,9 \}$.
I have read this understood [For any prime p>5 proving the existence of consecutive quadratic residues and consecutive quadratic non residues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3875005/for-any-prime-p5-proving-the-existence-of-consecutive-quadratic-residues-and-co)
How to do this how to show for at least one n ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose it were *false* and try to get a contradiction. For example, since $(\frac{1}{p}) = 1$, you would need $(\frac{2}{p}) = -1$. Since $(\frac{4}{p}) = 1$, what does that tell you about $(\frac{3}{p})$?  Then keep going and remember the Legendre symbol is multiplicative.

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: I gave you a starting point: suppose your goal were *not* correct, so you can't ever have $n$ and $n+1$ both be quadratic residues mod $p$. What does that tell you about $(\frac{3}{p})$?  Then think about what you can say about $(\frac{5}{p})$. And keep going.

Comment: But this works good lets say  (a/p) =1 for $a\in\{1,4,6,9\}$ and (b/p) =-1 for $b \in \{ 2,3,5,7,8\}$

Comment: I am not getting any contradiction.

Comment: With those constraints you actually have an example right in front of you.  Reread carefully what you are trying to show.

Comment: Yes this does not hold for prime p=7, 11,13,17.

Comment: Hence contradiction but it holds for all prime $\geq$ 7

Comment: I don't know how you are getting a contradiction.   Did you check $(\frac{n}{p})$ and $(\frac{n+1}{p})$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$, and 9?

Comment: How can we check if we don't know prime number greater than Or equal to seven.

Comment: @arbashn no no, the result is actually *true*.  If it's not true at $n = 1$ or $n = 4$ then it is true at $n = 9$.  I had wanted the OP to think about this to figure it out on their own.

Comment: @KCd You're right. I hadn't noticed the $n+1$, and foolishly considered only the given set.